# Installing mailparse extension to php

Tags: php, php-extension, email-parsing

I want to install mailparse extension to php ( os is windows, php version 5.2).
I use EasyPhp.

I copy `php_mailparse.dll` to `ext` folder, and add `extension=php_mailparse.dll` to `php.ini` file. But i get error

> mail_parse.dll specified module couldn't be found.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you try after restarting the webserver ?

Comment: Yes, i restart apache

Comment: `mail_parse.dll` or `php_mailparse.dll`?

Comment: php_mailparse.dll, that's my mistake, i find solution, u uninstall easyphp and install newer version (with newer php version) and everything is all right :)